# Как вывести изображение в QLabel без сохранения в файле?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyside2, barcode

Подскажите как вывести изображение не сохраняя его в файл? Может в оперативку как-то можно сохранить?

Не хочу каждый раз сохранять изображение, а потом снова его загружать. Есть способ напрямую выводить в `QLabel`?

**barcode_design.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>849</width>
    <height>677</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="editNum"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnGenerate">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Сгенерировать</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnPrint">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Печать</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import os
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QMainWindow, QApplication 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class BarcodeGenerate(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('barcode_design.ui', self)
        self.btnGenerate.clicked.connect(self.generate)
        self.show()
    
    def generate(self):
        self.eanNum = self.editNum.text()
        self.ean13 = barcode.get('ean13', self.eanNum, writer=ImageWriter())
        
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.ean13.save('barcode'))
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = BarcodeGenerate()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from io import BytesIO                                                         # +++

import barcode                                           # pip install python-barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from barcode import EAN13                                                      # +++

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                                     # +

#from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
# pyuic5 barcode_design.ui -o barcode_design_ui.py
#from barcode_design_ui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.editNum = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.editNum.setObjectName("editNum")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.editNum)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.btnGenerate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnGenerate.setObjectName("btnGenerate")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btnGenerate)
        self.btnPrint = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnPrint.setObjectName("btnPrint")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btnPrint)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnGenerate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сгенерировать"))
        self.btnPrint.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Печать"))


class BarcodeGenerate(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnGenerate.clicked.connect(self.generate)
        self.editNum.setText('123456789012')                                   # +++

    def generate(self):
        eanNum = self.editNum.text()
        ean = EAN13(eanNum, writer=ImageWriter())                              # +++
        rv = BytesIO()                                                         # +++
        ean.write(rv)                                                          # +++
        img = rv.getvalue()                                                    # +++
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(img)                                               # +++
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = BarcodeGenerate()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]